# Should Windows 8 be taking up 40GB of my HDD when my drive is compressed?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, compression

I want to install a game that requires 12GB on my computer with an HDD that shows 53GB total capacity, so I cleared everything off of it.

- All documents, pictures, downloads, desktop, etc empty
- Drive is compressed to save space
- Ran Disk Cleanup and removed every option there, gaining about 1GB of space
- Uninstalled all non-essential programs, all games, even my antivirus.

But I'm still 3GB short.

It appears that the Windows 8 OS is taking up 40GB by itself. I looked it up on Google and supposedly Windows 8 is only supposed to require half of that.

**Can/Should Windows 8 really be taking up this much space even with my drive compressed, and is there any way to reduce it?**

Comment: It is indeed possible.  What is taking up space is the required updates that you have installed since the initial installation.  While you can delete this data, doing will prevent your ability from fixing even the most basic system integrity problems, and is not a very good idea.

Comment: Both the paging file and hibernation file may be taking up a lot of space on your hard drive without being visible, it doesn't sound like you have another hard drive otherwise I'd recommend you move these to a different disk.

Comment: @Richard I actually have a 1TB external drive, but I cant install my game on it.  I'm using my computer's only USB input to connect to an external monitor. This will be fixed when I get a docking station, but for now I'm pretty much limited to my internal HDD.

Comment: Okay, you might want to update your question to include this information. I suspect you'll have both HIBERFIL.SYS and PAGEFILE.SYS files in the root of your C: drive taking up the missing space, these files could only be moved to another "fixed" drive.

Comment: @Richard what does "fixed" mean?

Comment: As in "not an external drive", I don't think you can move these hidden system files to an external USB drive for example.

https://superuser.com/questions/277834/how-to-delete-or-resize-pagefile-sys

Comment: And this: https://superuser.com/questions/402768/can-i-set-hiberfil-sys-to-another-drive

Comment: Sorry for spamming but this is the final one: https://superuser.com/questions/209541/windows-pagefile-size-with-large-ram-and-ssd

Comment: @Richard in one of those links the users memtions not wanting to turn of hibernation mode. Is this an option?

Comment: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-2082951/disable-hibernation-windows-windows.html describes how to do this, this may free up some disk space at the expense of not being able to hibernate.

Comment: Are you 100% positive you are connecting a monitor over a USB connection?  Because that would be extremely strange and likely isn't require to actually use the monitor.

Comment: @Ramhound yep. I ordered a triple monitor setup to connect to my Surface Pro 2, and that's how the company decided it should be connected, considering the limited connection mediums in the Surface tablet PC. There's also a connection to the Display Port.

Comment: Your external display is being connected over ONLY a USB connection that's weird, and frankly, ublikely when the device has a display port

Comment: @ramhound it's three displays. You cant connect three displays via one displayport. It requires a USB -> HDMI external video card + display port with daisy chain.

Comment: @ramhound we can continue this in chat if you like.

Comment: No; You provided the missing information.  I asked because somebody else 2 weeks ago swore his display was connected over USB and it actually wasn't

Comment: Technically you can daisy chain 2 DP1.2 monitors with a third being DP1.1 but if your monitors don't have DP support it is indeed not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find that HIBERFIL.SYS (a hidden system file) is taking up a lot of space on your main (internal) hard drive.

If you want to reclaim this space at the cost of not being able to hibernate your PC any more you can follow these instructions:

[How to disable hibernation](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-2082951/disable-hibernation-windows-windows.html)

Alternatively you can run the following from a Command Prompt which is running in Administrator Mode and this will achieve the same effect:

> powercfg -h off

Comment: Success. This worked. Weirdly, my hibernation setting was already off, but running this command cleared the space you're talking about. Installing my game now :)